# How do I keep my ruby twitter bot from replying multiple times to the same tweet?

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems, bots

I'm building a twitterbot using the Ruby twitter gem.
What i want it to do is

- a) check for the latest tweet from a certain user (=@....),
- b) fav it, and
- c) reply to it (tweeting a random sample from an array)
- d) wait for a minute, check again for new tweets.

This kinda works but it keeps replying to the latest tweet over and over again. Sadly, I don't know how to limit the thing to one reply per tweet. How do I get my bot to only reply once to a tweet?

```
    def search
      @client.search('from:@example').take(1).each do |tweet|
        puts tweet.user.screen_name
        puts tweet.text
        @client.favorite(tweet)
        @client.update(
          "@#{tweet.user.screen_name} #{@twit.sample}",
          in_reply_to_status_id: tweet.id)
        sleep 60
        search
      end
    end
```

Many thanks (I've been looking and trying myself for a couple of days now but I can't seem to find a solution. Sorry if i'm missing the obvious...)

Comment: I reject answering the question that will help to spam me later.

Comment: Yeah sorry, i see how this could happen. However i could use this bot as it is to spam people right now (and that's not how i intend to use it). In fact the person that i will be using it on knows about this and is ok with it. In any case this is more of a learning project anyways. I would just like to know how it's done, the bot itself won't be used a lot.

Comment: Fair enough :) you have to maintain a list of tweet ids of already replied tweets. It could be done in an instance variable (but that way it won’t survive restarts,) or in some persistent storage like file/db. In the very first line inside `each` you should check if the `id` is already known and skip acting if so. In the very last line inside `each` you should add the `id` of currently replied tweet to this list.

Comment: thanks a lot @mudasobwa , this seems to be a bit more complicated than i thought it would be (and in any case my ruby knowledge seems too limited atm, so...) but your answer made it a lot clearer, thank you! :)